# Get a (continuous) approximation for the equipotential lines of the function $ f(L,\Delta)=2^{-L}\binom{L}{\frac{L-\Delta}{2}}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial, gamma-function

I am interested in getting a (continuous) approximation for the equipotential lines of the function 
$$f(L,\Delta)=2^{-L}\binom{L}{\frac{L-\Delta}{2}}$$

So I tried to solve $const.=f(L,\Delta)$ for either $L$ or $\Delta$ using factorials for the binomial coefficient and then Stirling's formula for the factorials. But that leads to an equation that has terms of the form $(L-\Delta)^{L-\Delta}$ (or similar) and I don't know how to solve that for either $L$ or $\Delta$.

The equipotential lines look roughly like the silhouette of on egg. I was hoping that if I find an approximation of the binomial coefficient that is crude enough, I could derive an approximation for the equipotential lines in the form of (perhaps) an ellipse $\frac{L^2}{a^2}+\frac{\Delta^2}{b^2}=const.$

[image: equipotential lines of $f(L,\Delta)$]

**EDIT**

Claude Leibovici suggested an approach to approximating $f$ (see his answer below). I used his $O(\frac{1}{L})^5$ equation to get an approximation for equipotential lines of $f$.

[image: fitted equipotential lines of $f(L,\Delta)$]

Here, the dashed lines are results of Claude's approximation.

In case somebody is interested in reproducing this, here is my mathematica notebook:

[image: Mathematica notebook part 1]
[image: Mathematica notebook part 2]

Comment: If you have a tool for solving polynomial equations, I could provide you more terms for the expansion.

Comment: If you considered that my answer is useful, it would be very good that you add to your post a second plot using the expansion I gave.

Comment: I think that the approximation is better than it looks from the second plot. May I suggest you replace the second plot by another one showing the **contour lines** for the two functions. They really overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve for $\Delta$   the equation$$2^{-L}\binom{L}{\frac{L-\Delta}{2}}=\frac{2^{-L}\,\,L!}{\left(\frac{L-\Delta }{2}\right)!\,\, \left(\frac{L+\Delta }{2}\right)!}=k$$  take logarithms of both sides and, for each factorial, use Stirling approximation for large values of $L$ and continue expanding the result using Taylor expansions still for infinitely large values of $L$.

This would lead to
$$\log \left(2^{-L} \binom{L}{\frac{L-\Delta }{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2}{\pi  L}\right)-\frac{2 \Delta ^2+1}{4
   L}+\frac{\Delta ^2}{2 L^2}-\frac{2 \Delta ^4+8 \Delta ^2-1}{24
   L^3}+\frac{\Delta ^4}{4 L^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{L^5}\right)$$ which is a quadratic polynomial in $\Delta^2$. If you truncate to $O\left(\frac{1}{L^3}\right)$, the solution is immediate. For more accuracy, just continue the expansions to get cubic, quartic, quintic, sextic, $\cdots$, polynomials in $\Delta^2$.

For example, using $L=100$ and $k=0.05$ in the complete expansion given above, this would lead to $\Delta=9.683$ while the exact solution would be ... the same !

You need to play with it and see how good or bad this could be.

On my side, I made a contour plot and it seems to be quite good.

Assuming that you will not plan to go beyound $O\left(\frac{1}{L^5}\right)$, we  can simplify using Padé approximants and write 
$$-\frac{2 \Delta ^2+1}{4
   L}+\frac{\Delta ^2}{2 L^2}-\frac{2 \Delta ^4+8 \Delta ^2-1}{24
   L^3}+\frac{\Delta ^4}{4 L^4}=\frac{\alpha+\beta\, \Delta^2} {1+\gamma\,\Delta^2}$$ where
$$\alpha=\frac{1-6 L^2}{24 L^3}\qquad \beta=\frac{-24 L^5+48 L^4-54 L^3+26 L^2-11 L+1}{16 L^4 \left(3 L^2-3 L+2\right)}\qquad \gamma=\frac{3-L}{2 L \left(3 L^2-3 L+2\right)}$$ which let us with the simple linear equation in $\Delta ^2$
$$\color{blue}{\frac{\alpha+\beta\, \Delta^2} {1+\gamma\,\Delta^2}=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\pi L k^2 }{2} \right)}$$

**Edit**

I produced a table of $\log(k)$ computed using the above expansion as well as with the original equation.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
L & \Delta & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 100 & 0  & -2.53088 & -2.53088 \\
 100 & 10 & -3.02672 & -3.02672 \\
 100 & 20 & -4.52394 & -4.52416 \\
 100 & 30 & -7.05165 & -7.05410 \\
 100 & 40 & -10.6583 & -10.6726 \\
 100 & 50 & -15.4119 & -15.4693 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 200 & 0  & -2.87620 & -2.87620 \\
 200 & 10 & -3.12506 & -3.12506 \\
 200 & 20 & -3.87286 & -3.87287 \\
 200 & 30 & -5.12330 & -5.12337 \\
 200 & 40 & -6.88253 & -6.88296 \\
 200 & 50 & -9.15918 & -9.16083 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 300 & 0  & -3.07852 & -3.07852 \\
 300 & 10 & -3.24466 & -3.24466 \\
 300 & 20 & -3.74345 & -3.74346 \\
 300 & 30 & -4.57600 & -4.57601 \\
 300 & 40 & -5.74414 & -5.74419 \\
 300 & 50 & -7.25042 & -7.25064 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 400 & 0  & -3.22215 & -3.22215 \\
 400 & 10 & -3.34685 & -3.34685 \\
 400 & 20 & -3.72111 & -3.72111 \\
 400 & 30 & -4.34539 & -4.34539 \\
 400 & 40 & -5.22047 & -5.22048 \\
 400 & 50 & -6.34743 & -6.34748 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 500 & 0  & -3.33360 & -3.33360 \\
 500 & 10 & -3.43340 & -3.43340 \\
 500 & 20 & -3.73290 & -3.73290 \\
 500 & 30 & -4.23233 & -4.23234 \\
 500 & 40 & -4.93210 & -4.93210 \\
 500 & 50 & -5.83274 & -5.83276 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 600 &  0 & -3.42467 & -3.42467 \\
 600 & 10 & -3.50787 & -3.50787 \\
 600 & 20 & -3.75751 & -3.75751 \\
 600 & 30 & -4.17374 & -4.17374 \\
 600 & 40 & -4.75677 & -4.75677 \\
 600 & 50 & -5.50694 & -5.50694 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 700 & 0 & -3.50169 & -3.50169 \\
 700 & 10 & -3.57302 & -3.57302 \\
 700 & 20 & -3.78703 & -3.78703 \\
 700 & 30 & -4.14382 & -4.14382 \\
 700 & 40 & -4.64353 & -4.64353 \\
 700 & 50 & -5.28637 & -5.28637 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 800 & 0  & -3.56841 & -3.56841 \\
 800 & 10 & -3.63083 & -3.63083 \\
 800 & 20 & -3.81812 & -3.81812 \\
 800 & 30 & -4.13034 & -4.13034 \\
 800 & 40 & -4.56758 & -4.56758 \\
 800 & 50 & -5.12997 & -5.12997 \\
     &    &          &          \\
 900 & 0 & -3.62727 & -3.62727 \\
 900 & 10 & -3.68276 & -3.68276 \\
 900 & 20 & -3.84926 & -3.84926 \\
 900 & 30 & -4.12680 & -4.12680 \\
 900 & 40 & -4.51546 & -4.51546 \\
 900 & 50 & -5.01533 & -5.01533 \\
    &    &          &          \\
 1000 & 0 & -3.67992 & -3.67992 \\
 1000 & 10 & -3.72987 & -3.72987 \\
 1000 & 20 & -3.87973 & -3.87973 \\
 1000 & 30 & -4.12954 & -4.12954 \\
 1000 & 40 & -4.47933 & -4.47933 \\
 1000 & 50 & -4.92919 & -4.92919
\end{array}
\right)$$ This looks to be very promising.

If you want a larger expansion, you could get
$$\log \left(2^{-L} \binom{L}{\frac{L-\Delta }{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2}{\pi  L}\right)-\frac{2 \Delta ^2+1}{4
   L}+\frac{\Delta ^2}{2 L^2}-\frac{2 \Delta ^4+8 \Delta ^2-1}{24
   L^3}+\frac{\Delta ^4}{4 L^4}-\frac{2 \Delta ^6+20 \Delta ^4-16 \Delta ^2+3}{60 L^5}+\frac{\Delta ^6}{6 L^6}-\frac{6 \Delta ^8+112 \Delta ^6-224 \Delta ^4+256 \Delta ^2-51}{336L^7}+\frac{\Delta ^8}{8 L^8}-\frac{2 \Delta ^{10}+60 \Delta ^8-224 \Delta ^6+640 \Delta ^4-768 \Delta ^2+155}{189L^9}+\frac{\Delta ^{10}}{10 L^{10}}+O\left(\frac{1}{L^{11}}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you @Claude Leibovici! I tried to follow your steps to the $O(1/L^4)$ approximation, but couldn't quite follow. How did the equation look like before you used the Taylor expansion?

Comment: Also, I plotted the $O(1/L^4)$ approximations together with the exact results and it works quite nicely, but only if I include a factor $\pi$ in the $\log$ on the left-hand side. Could you check if there is a typo in that equation? I will check my code again.

Comment: @AliceSchwarze. I do confirm my results. You cannot stop at $O(1/L^4)$ because $\Delta^4$ appears in the next term. You must use it as it is written to  $O(1/L^5)$. The last approximation (written in blue) could be better. (at least much simpler since you get $\Delta^2$ directly. I could have still better approximations but the $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ become quite longer.

Comment: @AliceSchwarze. What I woul appreciate is that you add to your post the plot with the approximation for comparaison. By the way, if you think my answer is of some use, you could accept it.

Comment: @AliceSchwarze. Doing the first step, before Taylor expansion, the expression is $$\frac{210 L^4-7 L^2+2}{2520 L^5}+\frac{1}{6 (\Delta -L)}-\frac{1}{6 (\Delta
   +L)}+\frac{1}{45 (L-\Delta )^3}+\frac{1}{45 (\Delta +L)^3}+\frac{8}{315 (\Delta
   -L)^5}-\frac{8}{315 (\Delta +L)^5}+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2}{L-\Delta
   }\right)+\frac{1}{2} ((\Delta -L) \log (L-\Delta )-(\Delta +L) \log (\Delta +L)+2
   L \log (L))+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{\pi  \Delta +\pi 
   L}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{L}\right)$$

Comment: If I use Stirling's approximation $\log n! \approx n \log n -n$ on the factorials in $\log(2^-L\binom{L}{(L-\Delta)/2}), I get some of the latter terms in your comment above, but not all. It looks like you expanded something at this stage already to get the first 7 terms in your comment. What was that?

Comment: As you can see, I am still working on understanding your approach. Once I have done that, I am happy to make a new plot with the approximation and accept your answer.

Comment: @AliceSchwarze. You used too less. Going to $O(1/n^7)$ $$\log(n!)=n (\log (n)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({n}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{1}{360 n^3}+\frac{1}{1260
   n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$